# Firebase authentication Twitter API Login "Nothing to see here"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, twitter

We have an iOS app connected to Firebase that calls on the Twitter API for authentication. We are being redirected fine to the Twitter form to enter crendetials. After entering the account and password, our callback_url is not executed and instead we see “Nothing to see here”. Does anyone else is having this issue?. The Twitter Developer Portal is configured fine with Firebase's callback URL, also have the website, terms and policy fields set. I guess if anything wrong at the portal we wouldn't be redirected from the app to the sign-in form. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: I am also stock on this problem.

Comment: Facing same issue for quite a few days!! Twitter seems to be completely silent on all platforms!

Answer (score 2):

I logged with my twitter @ username and it worked. However the problem persists if logging using email address.

Comment: Thanks! I'm developing an android app and facing the same issue. And using username instead of email works for android as well. It's really frustrating that there's so few useful materials available in the internet for twitter login...